# Create file of any type in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Right now, when creating a file of some format (e.g. PHP files) in Windows Explorer, I always have to use "Create new text file" to create a file and then rename it (often via console, because extensions are hidden - I know I could disable that feature).

Is there a way to simply add an option to create a new file of any type that simply lets me type in the extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes i open cmd in this folder and type something like

```
copy nul filname.ext
```

this hint create empty file with extension that you need.

Answer (score 3):

I just went for showing file extensions again.

Answer (score 1):

If you load up a blank document in notepad, fill in some content, and hit save.. in the save dialog change the file type to "All Files", then give the file a name (including the extension, like "my file.php").

Comment: Yes, I know, but that is exactly what I do not wanna do.

Answer (score 1):

You can go  in the powershell or the command prompt and use the following command:

```
fsutil file createnew name.ext 0
```

Comment: I have restructured your post as it was flagged as low quality, if you feel it's too radical a change, please roll back or edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file of any type in windows by making this change:

OS: Win 10 (More or less in other Win versions it will be the same)

- Open 'Control Panel'
- Click 'Appearance & Personalization'
- Click 'File Explorer Options'
- It opens a dialog, click on 'View' Tab.
- In the list, un-check 'Hide Extensions for known file types'
- [This image may help you navigate to this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg3dH.png)

Once you make this change, go to any folder; right click -> new file -> Type name of the file and the extension you wish.

E.g You want to create a javascript file by name 'helloworld', just right click new file -> type helloworld.js (That's all, it may prompt a window just say Ok)